# How do I disable my Seekbar in Android with a Switch?

Tags: java, android

I want to disable my Seekbar and buttons with a switch which is Powerswitch
Here is a code snippet:

```
seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                    String sval = String.valueOf(i);
                    speakerVal.setText(sval); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });

            // button - Favorite Channel ABC
            cabc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonABC);
            cabc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Set Favorite
                    curChannel.setText("007");

                }
            });
```

and here is my switch code:

```
final Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

more switch code:

```
 public void onSwitchClicked(View view) {
        final TextView PowerSwitch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PwrSwitchVal);
        Switch sw = (Switch) view;
        if (sw.isChecked()) {
            PowerSwitch.setText("ON");

            pwr = true;
        } else {
            PowerSwitch.setText("OFF");
            pwr = false;

        }
    }
```

I know I can use the switch.isChecked(), but when I change the seekba1.setEnabled(false), I can't seem to get it to turn back on.

I haven't even tried to disable the buttons yet.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onSwitchClicked` method, you should be calling `seekbar.setEnabled` in the if checked if-else statement. If checked `seekbar.setEnabled(true)` else `seekbar.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: thanks, I tried that but that did not work... I did however get this to work by coding a method "onCheckedChanged" for the switch...there I could setEnabled the seekbar as well as all of my buttons. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                                boolean arg1) {
                            if (arg1) {
                                seekbar1.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            else{
                                seekbar1.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                        }
                    });
```